# Read hive from R dockerized

Tags: r, docker, shiny, hive

I have a shiny aplication with read a data from hive hdfs. Here is my code to connect hive with shiny R :

```
drv <- JDBC("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver",
            classPath = c("/app/jdbc/hive-jdbc-standalone.jar")) 

conn <- dbConnect(drv, 
                  "jdbc:hive2://10.35.105.35:10000/default", "hive", "hive")
```

I want to dockerize my shiny app, and successfull to build the image smoothly without error. When I run the image as a container no error on the logs, but there is no massage like "Listening on 'port'" and when I open localhost:3838 , my application doesn't open. no clue for this error or missing something. Can someone help me for fixing my problem? or someone have blueprint to get data from hive with r or python in docker and wanna share the dockerfile?

here is my dockerfile rightnow

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:latest

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    openjdk-8-jdk \
    openjdk-8-jre 

ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
ENV PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin


ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive


RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
    curl \
    gnupg \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get update -qq \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install msodbcsql17


RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" upgrade


RUN apt-get install -y r-cran-rjava


RUN R CMD javareconf


RUN apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
    libxml2-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libsqlite3-dev \
    libmariadbd-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    unixodbc-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libssl-dev


RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get clean


RUN R -e "install.packages(pkgs=c('RODBC','odbc','DBI','shinyjs','dplyr','lubridate','ggplot2','hrbrthemes','tidyr','shinyWidgets','shinydashboardPlus','flexdashboard','shiny','tidyverse','shinydashboard', 'xgboost', 'DT', 'plotly', 'tidymodels', 'ggridges', 'tidytext', 'RJDBC'), repos='https://cran.rstudio.com')"


WORKDIR /app


COPY global.R /app/
COPY ui.R /app/
COPY server.R /app/
COPY oee_tampo_flt.csv /app/
COPY jdbc /app/jdbc

RUN chmod 777 -R .


EXPOSE 3838

CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/app', host='0.0.0.0', port=3838)"]
```

---

Edited :
I fixed this problem by change the jdk and jre installation version on the dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    openjdk-11-jdk \
    openjdk-11-jre 

ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/
```

Comment: How did you start your docker image?

Comment: run manually from image menu on docker